# Same Queries on Same database at same time but Different Results?? [Big Query]

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, google-bigquery

I am executing some mysql-type-queries on a dataset using Google Big Query. Both the queries are almost same(they differ only in the ordering of 2 columns retrieved using SELECT, all the other parameters/conditions are same) and yet they give two different outputs when executed one after other on same database. I am a beginner in BigQuery as well as MySQL. Please Help.

The queries and results are given below

QUERY 1:

```
SELECT web100_log_entry.snap.MinRTT AS rttval,
       web100_log_entry.connection_spec.remote_ip AS rip
FROM [measurement-lab:m_lab.2010_01]
WHERE IS_EXPLICITLY_DEFINED(connection_spec.client_geolocation.continent_code)
  AND IS_EXPLICITLY_DEFINED(web100_log_entry.log_time)
  AND IS_EXPLICITLY_DEFINED(connection_spec.client_geolocation.country_code)
  AND IS_EXPLICITLY_DEFINED(web100_log_entry.snap.MinRTT)
  AND web100_log_entry.log_time > 1262304000
  AND web100_log_entry.log_time < 1262476800
  AND connection_spec.client_geolocation.continent_code='EU'
  AND connection_spec.client_geolocation.country_code='FR'
```

QUERY 2:

```
SELECT web100_log_entry.connection_spec.remote_ip AS rip,
       web100_log_entry.snap.MinRTT AS rttval
FROM [measurement-lab:m_lab.2010_01]
WHERE IS_EXPLICITLY_DEFINED(connection_spec.client_geolocation.continent_code)
  AND IS_EXPLICITLY_DEFINED(web100_log_entry.log_time)
  AND IS_EXPLICITLY_DEFINED(connection_spec.client_geolocation.country_code)
  AND IS_EXPLICITLY_DEFINED(web100_log_entry.snap.MinRTT)
  AND web100_log_entry.log_time > 1262304000
  AND web100_log_entry.log_time < 1262476800
  AND connection_spec.client_geolocation.continent_code='EU'
  AND connection_spec.client_geolocation.country_code='FR'
```

RESULT 1:

```
+------------+---------------+
|   rttval   |      rip      |
+------------+---------------+
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
| 4294967295 | 92.161.77.187 |
+------------+---------------+
```

RESULT 2 :

```
+-------------+------------+
|     rip     |   rttval   |
+-------------+------------+
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
| 82.233.86.3 | 4294967295 |
+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: What is your question here exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you pasted here is just the first displayed page of the results, there are 3254299 rows total, and they come in different order (even for the same query the can come in different order), because there is no ORDER BY clause.

Comment: How did you get to know that there are 3254299 rows in total?

Comment: Also how can I access the next page ? I want to see all the results

Comment: When you are using BigQuery UI, you see at the bottom the total number of rows in the result. And controls to go to the next page. Or you can just download the result as CSV and view it in the tool of your choice (like Excel)